# PreparedStatement with conditional query

Tags: java, jdbc, conditional-statements, prepared-statement

I have code that is currently using a `String` to build a query, concatenating the values and using directly `executeQuery` to obtain the result (I know, it's a bad practice). Besides that, the resulting query depends on many conditions so, the code is something like:

```
String query = "select * from my_table where field1 = " + value1;

if (somecondition) {
    query += " and field2 = " + value2;
} else if (othercondition) {
    query += " or field3 = " + value3;
} else {
    query += " and field4 = " + value + " and field5 = " + value5;
}

ResultSet result = connection.executeQuery(query);
```

Well, this is a very simplify example, but as you can see the query's values, number of fields, etc, depends on many conditions and everything is concatenated.

I need to turn that into a `PreparedStatements` query, but, as far as I know, before creating the prepared statement, I need to have the whole query built, then set the parameters with:

`preparedStatement.setInt(1, value);`

And so on. However, in my scenario, I need to set some values before knowing the rest of the query, then, depending on the condition, set one or another parameter for the rest of the query. Is that possible with prepared statements? Or do I need to change completely the logic of the code and build the whole query for each condition and then set the values with the preparestatement?

Comment: You can build the query dynamically like you already did, just use the placeholders `?` for the values and set them with the `setXXX()` methods (based on the conditions you have).

Comment: You can collect a `List<Object>` with the values while you're constructing the query, and then after preparing the query use `setObject` to set all values, or you need to repeat this twice, once for constructing the query, and once for setting the values.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```java
        String query = "select * from my_table where field1 = ?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
        if (somecondition)
        {
            query += " and field2 = ?";
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, value2);
        } else if (othercondition)
        {
            query += " or field3 = ?";
            preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, value3);
        } else
            {
                query += " and field4 = ? and field5 = ?";
                preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, value4);
                preparedStatement.setString(3, value5);
            }

        preparedStatement.setString(1, value1);
        ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
```